# Is it possible to run on iis some sample service and also restful service?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, iis, windows-services

I need to write some application that make 3 things

1. Read data from some queue
2. Save the data from the queue
3. Expose interface on restful that return the last data that was rad
   from the queue

I wrote the part that expose the restful service and the host is iis. 
Now, i need to write the part that read from the queue and save the data.

From what i understand - the **reading from queue** part must run on separate process because it need to read from the queue all the time 
( every 3 second it must make the queue reading part ) even if no body call any restful method.

Is there any way to make all those part in one process ?

I mean that i want to have a application that run as a service and make the queue sample and also expose the restful interface on the iis ( the iis is the host )

Comment: You can use the job scheduling (Quartz) which will run on every specified interval..  http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/index.html

Comment: i know hiw to do it on two processes - i want to do it one one process

Comment: i may be wrong but in our case for license validation we used create a job on start the application(web/ restful service). and it will trigger on required do it's task. Here also u have u vr restful service which is hosted in iis on start of service u can schedule a multiple jobs to do what u wanted to do..